# Why F12 won't work as hotkey to open 'Save as ' dialogue box in Word/Excel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

F12 is the hotkey to open 'save as' dialogue in word/excel 2007, why when i do that on my own word/excel, F12 won't work as hotkey to open 'save as ' dialogue box? I am using chrome, and F12 is the key to open 'print' box, is that why ?

Comment: Wha _does_ happen when you press F12? Nothing? Something other than open "Save As" dialogue?

Comment: @BigChris nothing happened.

Comment: OK, Do you have a "F.Lock" key on your keyboard that may have been pressed. Many keyboards (especially laptops) have multiple functions or can have the "Fx" keys disabled. Perhaps your F keys have been accidentally turned off? E.g. http://sydneypcug.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/f-lock-key1.png

Comment: @BigChris i can't find where the Fx key is, and i am using a desktop now.

Comment: By "Fx" I mean F1, F2, F3 etc. Can you share a picture of your keyboard? Or find an image?

Comment: @BigChris i do have F1 to F12, and how do i upload a pix to here, it doesn't seem to have a pic upload Function here. Pls instruct.

Comment: You can't - if you can upload it to a service and publish the link to us

Comment: @BigChris sorry can you advice how to do that to a service?

Comment: Somewhere like PhotoBucket or if you can make a photo publicly available through Google Drive or DropBox etc?!

Comment: @BigChris i can take pic with cell, but i can not load it to drop box or flickr, is blocked in our country i think. Any alternative?

Comment: @BigChris now i have the pix on my pc, however, our ofc won't allow us to install anything on our ofc pc, what can i do? i remember once there is a website i can upload and send my link, do you know any?

Comment: @BigChris finally with the help of a friend...https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojxr7tn9bkc7opr/photo_1410942819008_smaller.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vskdrinxwakbwgj/photo_1410942628562_smaller.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Ok, you don't have additional function buttons. That's good. You may have accidentally turned off (or Office may have forgotten) the keyboard shortcuts. Read here to get to the right Window: http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-20.html

Comment: @BigChris for word is fine, however for excel how can you assign a hotkey ?I am excel 2007

Comment: Does it have similar options in the Excel options screens?

Comment: @BigChris not at all, and i have done search online, the results i got says impossible, but i doubt what i found, coz it's quite unlikely a smart thing like excel doesn't have this function.

Answer (score 0):

To the right of my F12 key is a [F] Lock key.  This toggles using any F# key in it's quick action function (i.e. F5=Refresh, or F12 = Print Screen for my Snagit program)

I am using a Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop I pressed the Fn key along with Esc and it turns the Function keys back on. It was driving me crazy!